Adjustment for 3 variables
I have tried to make an adjustment for my data but I got results only for number of certification and not for 2 other variables. I can't understand where is the issue. I am beginner in R so if anybody can help me?
Results
library(icarus)

## Obtenir des poids totaux pour chaque status jurdique
total_weights_TE01 <- aggregate(weight ~ TE01, data = weighted_data, FUN = sum)
print(total_weights_TE01)
## Obtenir des poids totaux pour le nb des bouteilles
total_weights_etiquette <- aggregate(weight ~ etiquette_nb_bouteilles, data = weighted_data, FUN = sum)
print(total_weights_etiquette)
## Obtenir des poids totaux pour le nb des certificats
total_weights_certifs <- aggregate(weight ~ nb_env_certifs, data = weighted_data, FUN = sum)
print(total_weights_certifs)

#Ici j'ai essayé de prendre ce que nous devront obtenir avec 15956
mar1 <- c("TE01", 7, 6575.27473, 613.69231, 87.67033, 
          2630.10989, 4120.50549, 1402.72527, 526.02198) #status_juridique
mar2 <- c("etiquette_nb_bouteilles", 3, 4909.53846, 87.67033, 
          10958.79121, 0, 0, 0, 0) #nb_bouteilles
mar3 <- c("nb_env_certifs", 3, 8401.740, 6356.099, 
          1198.161, 0, 0, 0, 0) #nb_certifs

marges <- rbind(mar1, mar2, mar3)


wCalesLogit <- calibration(data=weighted_data, marginMatrix=marges, colWeights="weight", method="raking",
                           bounds=c(0.1,10), calibTolerance=0.05, description=TRUE)

I still not sure I got if we need to put initial weight as a part of each row from all rows we have in our database or according to the external data.

Welcome to SO, Natalia! Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for these reasons - and these.
